# .NET Chart Controls in Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox

Tags: .net, sharepoint, charts, sandbox

I'm trying to use the .NET Chart Controls in my Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox solution. I have downloaded and installed the MSChart for .NET 3.5 [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422).

Does anyone know if the .NET Chart Controls are supported in Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox solutions?

I tried to find examples and I can only find examples for Sharepoint 2010 (not Sandbox) and in these you need to add assembly references in you web.config file, which is not possible in Sandbox. This is an example of using .NET Chart in Sharepoint http://mosshowto.blogspot.com.au/2008/12/asp-net-chart-control-sharepoint.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A chart web part comes out of the box in SharePoint 2010.  See [article](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/02/24/impress-the-boss-with-the-sharepoint-2010-chart-web-part.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Emmie, that is a good start but I have to do from Visual Studio and not from the SharePoint site. How is that possible?

Comment: Why is it that you have to do it from Visual Studio?  Are you creating a web part for SharePoint?  If so then why re-invent the wheel.  Are you trying to wrap the existing web part in a Sandbox solution?  Have you thought about using a site template?

Comment: The reason why I want to do it from Visual Studio is it's a requirement from a client.

I'm trying to use the code from this sample http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: Will a site definition work for you?  Check out this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208383/Custom-Site-Definition).

Comment: I have tried that but I think I'm missing a reference/assembly/namespace or something like that somewhere.

In my web part I have the following:

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" %>`
`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" %>`

and I'm trying to add the chart by this simple code: `<asp:Chart ID="newChart" runat="server"></asp:Chart>`

Comment: Do you have the assembly registered as safe in your web.config file?

Comment: I have registered in the Package.Template.xml - you don't have access to the web.config file in Sandbox solutions.

Comment: Look at this...  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/29c02114-19a4-4f68-8043-dd1341634656

Comment: I can get that to work in a Sharepoint Farm solution when I **modify the web.config file**. But I **can't** modify the web.config file in a Sharepoint Sandbox solution.

Comment: I believe there is some XML that you may be able to add safe controls to for the web part.  Have you tried that?  Take a look at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798301.aspx).  Also look at the rules for a Sandbox solution [here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-11-Top_10_things_to_consider_when_writing_SandBoxed_Solutions.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use .Net charts control in SP2010 sandbox.
I usually generate JSON data on the server, and then the graph on the client side using JavaScript and HighCharts http://www.highcharts.com/.

It does the job.